# ng-change event not firing inside the loop

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-change

```js
function friendControllerTest($scope, $http) {
    $scope.loading = true;
    $scope.addMode = false;
    $scope.countryList = [];
    $scope.stateList = [];

    function getAllCountry() {
        $http({
            method: 'Get',
            url: '/Home/GetCountry'
        }).success(function (data) {
            $scope.countryList = data;
        }).error(function () {
            $scope.errorMessage = 'Not found';
        });
    }

    function getStatebyCountryId(Id) {
        $scope.stateList = null;
        if (Id) {           // Check here country Id is null or not
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: '/Home/GetStateByCountryId/',
                data: JSON.stringify({ CountryId:Id })
            }).success(function (data) {
                $scope.stateList = data;
            }).error(function (data) {
                alert(data.message);
                $scope.message = 'not found';
            });
        }
        else {
            $scope.stateList = null;
        }
    }


    $scope.GetStatesList = function (id) {
        if (id) {           // Check here country Id is null or not
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: '/Home/GetStateByCountryId/',
                data: JSON.stringify({ CountryId: id })
            }).success(function (data) {
                $scope.stateList = data;
            }).error(function (data) {
                alert(data.message);
                $scope.message = 'not found';
            });
        }
        else {
            $scope.stateList = null;
        }
    }



    $scope.myMethod = function () {
        var text = $scope.newfriend.SearchText;
        $http.get('../Home/GetFriendsList', { params: { 'text': text } }).success(function (data) {
            $scope.friends = data;
        })
          .error(function () {
              $scope.error = "An Error has occured while loading posts!";
          });
    }


    $http.get('../Home/GetFriendsList').success(function (data) {
        alert("list called")
        $scope.friends = data;
        $scope.loading = false;
    })
   .error(function () {
       $scope.error = "An Error has occured while loading posts!";
       $scope.loading = false;
   });

    $scope.toggleAdd = function () {
        $scope.addMode = !$scope.addMode;
        if ($scope.addMode) {
            getAllCountry();
        }
    };

    $scope.toggleEdit = function () { 
        this.friend.editMode = !this.friend.editMode;
        getAllCountry();
        if (this.friend.Country.Id > 0)
            getStatebyCountryId(this.friend.Country.Id);
    };

    $scope.add = function () {
        $scope.loading = true;
        var newfriend = {
            firstname: $scope.newfriend.firstname,
            lastname: $scope.newfriend.lastName,
            address: $scope.newfriend.address,
            postalcode: $scope.newfriend.PostalCode,
            notes: $scope.newfriend.Notes,
            CountryId: $scope.newfriend.Country.Id,
            StateId: $scope.newfriend.State.Id
        }
        $http.post('../Home/AddFriends', newfriend).success(function (data) {
            alert("Added Successfully!!");
            $scope.addMode = false;
            $scope.friends.push(data);
            $scope.loading = false;
            $scope.newfriend = "";
        }).error(function (data) {
            $scope.error = "An Error has occured while Adding Friend! " + data;
            $scope.loading = false;
        });
    };

    $scope.save = function () {
        $scope.loading = true;
        var frien = this.friend;
        $http.put('../Home/EditFriend', frien).success(function (data) {
            alert("Saved Successfully!!");
            frien.editMode = false;
            $scope.loading = false;
        }).error(function (data) {
            $scope.error = "An Error has occured while Saving Friend! " + data;
            $scope.loading = false;
        });
    };

    $scope.deletefriend = function () {
        $scope.loading = true;
        var friendid = this.friend.Id;
        $http.delete('../Home/RemoveFriend/' + friendid).success(function (data) {
            alert("Deleted Successfully!!");
            $.each($scope.friends, function (i) {
                if ($scope.friends[i].Id === friendid) {
                    $scope.friends.splice(i, 1);
                    return false;
                }
            });
            $scope.loading = false;
        }).error(function (data) {
            $scope.error = "An Error has occured while Saving Friend! " + data;
            $scope.loading = false;
        });
    };
}
```

```html
<html data-ng-app="" data-ng-controller="friendControllerTest">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <div class="container">
        <strong class="error">{{ error }}</strong>
        <div id="mydiv" data-ng-show="loading">
            <img src="Images/ajax-loader1.gif" class="ajax-loader" />
        </div>
       
        <p data-ng-hide="addMode">
            <a data-ng-click="toggleAdd()" href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-primary">Add New
            </a>
        </p>
        <form name="addFriend" data-ng-show="addMode" style="width: 600px; margin: 0px auto;">
            <label>FirstName:</label><input type="text" data-ng-model="newfriend.firstname" required />
            <label>LastName:</label><input type="text" data-ng-model="newfriend.lastName" required />
            <label>Address:</label><input type="text" data-ng-model="newfriend.address" required />
            <label>Country:</label>
           
            <select ng-model="newfriend.Country" ng-options="c.Name for c in countryList track by c.Id" ng-change="GetStatesList(newfriend.Country.Id)">
                <option value="">Select Country</option>
            </select>
            <label>State:</label>

            <select ng-model="newfriend.State" ng-options="s.Name for s in stateList track by s.Id">
                <option value="">Select State</option>
            </select>
            <label>PostalCode:</label><input type="text" data-ng-model="newfriend.PostalCode" required />
            <label>Notes:</label><input type="text" data-ng-model="newfriend.Notes" required />
            <br />
            <br />
            <input type="submit" value="Add" data-ng-click="add()" data-ng-disabled="!addFriend.$valid" class="btn btn-primary" />
            <input type="button" value="Cancel" data-ng-click="toggleAdd()" class="btn btn-primary" />
            <br />
            <br />
        </form>
        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" style="width: 800px">
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <td>FirstName</td>
                <th>LastName</th>
                <th>Address</th>
                <th>Country</th>
                <th>State</th>
                <th>PostalCode</th>
                <th>Notes</th>
            </tr>

            <tr data-ng-repeat="friend in friends">
                <td><strong>{{ friend.Id }}</strong></td>
                <td>
                    <p data-ng-hide="friend.editMode">{{ friend.firstname}}</p>
                    <input data-ng-show="friend.editMode" type="text" data-ng-model="friend.firstname" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p data-ng-hide="friend.editMode">{{ friend.lastname }}</p>
                    <input data-ng-show="friend.editMode" type="text" data-ng-model="friend.lastname" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p data-ng-hide="friend.editMode">{{ friend.address }}</p>
                    <input data-ng-show="friend.editMode" type="text" data-ng-model="friend.address" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p data-ng-hide="friend.editMode">{{ friend.Country.Name }}</p>
                    <select data-ng-show="friend.editMode" ng-model="friend.Country" ng-options="c.Name for c in countryList track by c.Id" ng-change="$parent.GetStatesList(friend.Country.Id)">
                        <option value="">Select Country</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p data-ng-hide="friend.editMode">{{friend.State.Name }}</p>
                    <select data-ng-show="friend.editMode" ng-model="friend.State" ng-options="s.Name for s in stateList track by s.Id">
                        <option value="">Select State</option>
                    </select>
                </td>


                <td>
                    <p data-ng-hide="friend.editMode">{{ friend.postalcode }}</p>
                    <input data-ng-show="friend.editMode" type="text" data-ng-model="friend.postalcode" />
                </td>

                <td>
                    <p data-ng-hide="friend.editMode">{{ friend.notes }}</p>
                    <input data-ng-show="friend.editMode" type="text" data-ng-model="friend.notes" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p data-ng-hide="friend.editMode"><a data-ng-click="toggleEdit(friend)" href="javascript:;">Edit</a> | <a data-ng-click="deletefriend(friend)" href="javascript:;">Delete</a></p>
                    <p data-ng-show="friend.editMode"><a data-ng-click="save(friend)" href="javascript:;">Save</a> | <a data-ng-click="toggleEdit(friend)" href="javascript:;">Cancel</a></p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <hr />
    </div>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/angularjs")
    <script src="~/Scripts/MyScript.js"></script>
</body>
```

I am trying to open my Country and state dropdown in edit mode and so far i am successfull in that.

But the only problem is when i am clicking on any record to open in edit mode my both country and state dropdown are binding correctly but when i am selecting other country from country dropdown then my ng-change is not firing and i dont know why.

**This is my view for adding a new record**:

```
<select ng-model="newfriend.Country" ng-options="c.Name for c in countryList track by c.Id" ng-change="GetStatesList()">
                <option value="">Select Country</option>
            </select>

            <label>State:</label>
            <select ng-model="newfriend.State" ng-options="s.Name for s in stateList track by s.Id">
                <option value="">Select State</option>
            </select>
```

**My Controller**:

```
    function friendControllerTest($scope, $http) {
             $scope.GetStatesList = function () {
                  //server side call to fetch state by country id
            }
 $scope.toggleEdit = function () { 
            this.friend.editMode = !this.friend.editMode;
            getAllCountry();
            if (this.friend.Country.Id > 0)
                getStatebyCountryId(this.friend.Country.Id);
        };


      };
```

**My Display records view**:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover" style="width: 800px">
 <tr data-ng-repeat="friend in friends">
  <td>
                    <p data-ng-hide="friend.editMode">{{ friend.Country.Name }}</p>
                    <select data-ng-show="friend.editMode" ng-model="friend.Country" ng-options="c.Name for c in countryList track by c.Id" ng-change="GetStatesList()">
                        <option value="">Select Country</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p data-ng-hide="friend.editMode">{{friend.State.Name }}</p>
                    <select data-ng-show="friend.editMode" ng-model="friend.State" ng-options="s.Name for s in stateList track by s.Id">
                        <option value="">Select State</option>
                    </select>
                </td>

</tr>
<table>



public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Home/
        private FriendsEntities db = new FriendsEntities();
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult GetFriendsList(string text)
        {

            var data = db.Friends.Select
                                (
                                    d => new FriendModel
                                    {
                                        Id=d.Id,
                                        firstname = d.firstname,
                                        lastname = d.lastname,
                                        address = d.address,
                                        notes = d.notes,
                                        postalcode = d.postalcode,
                                        Country = d.Country.Friends.Select
                                                                   (
                                                                        x => new CountryModel
                                                                        {
                                                                            Id=x.Country.Id,
                                                                            Name = x.Country.Name
                                                                        }
                                                                   ).FirstOrDefault(),
                                        State = d.State.Friends.Select
                                                               (
                                                                    s => new StateModel
                                                                    {
                                                                        Id=s.State.Id,
                                                                        Name = s.State.Name
                                                                    }
                                                               ).FirstOrDefault()

                                    }
                                ).ToList();
           return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddFriends(Friends FriendsModel)
        {
            var result = db.Friends.Add(FriendsModel);
            db.SaveChanges();
            var data = db.Friends.Where(t => t.Id == result.Id).Select
                                     (
                                            d => new FriendModel
                                            {
                                                Id=d.Id,
                                                firstname = d.firstname,
                                                lastname = d.lastname,
                                                address = d.address,
                                                notes = d.notes,
                                                postalcode = d.postalcode,
                                                Country = d.Country.Friends.Select
                                                                   (
                                                                        x => new CountryModel
                                                                        {
                                                                            Id=x.Country.Id,
                                                                            Name = x.Country.Name
                                                                        }

                                                                   ).FirstOrDefault(),
                                                State = d.State.Friends.Select
                                                                       (
                                                                           b => new StateModel
                                                                           {
                                                                               Id=b.State.Id,
                                                                               Name = b.State.Name
                                                                           }
                                                                       ).FirstOrDefault()
                                            }

                                     ).SingleOrDefault();

            return Json(data);
        }


        public ActionResult RemoveFriend(int id)
        {
            Friends friend = db.Friends.Find(id);
              db.Friends.Remove(friend);
              db.SaveChanges();
              return Json(friend);
        }

        public JsonResult GetCountryState()
        {
            List<CountryModel> Country = new List<CountryModel>().ToList();
            Country.Add(new CountryModel() { Id = 0, Name = "Select Country" });
            var Data = db.Country.Select
                                (
                                    d => new CountryModel
                                    {
                                        Id = d.Id,
                                        Name = d.Name,
                                        State = d.State.Select
                                        (
                                             x => new StateModel
                                             {
                                                 Id = x.Id,
                                                 Name = x.Name
                                             }
                                        ).ToList()
                                    }
                                ).ToList();
            Country.AddRange(Data);
            return Json(Country, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        public JsonResult GetCountry()
        {
            var Data = db.Country.Select
                                (
                                    d => new CountryModel
                                    {
                                        Id = d.Id,
                                        Name = d.Name,
                                    }
                                ).ToList();
            return Json(Data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        public JsonResult GetStateByCountryId(int CountryId)
        {
                var getStateList = db.State.Where(p => p.CountryId == CountryId).Select(x => new { x.Id, x.Name }).ToList();
                return Json(getStateList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }




        [HttpPut]
        public ActionResult EditFriend(Friends  FriendModel)
        {
            Friends friend = db.Friends.Find(FriendModel.Id);
            friend.firstname = FriendModel.firstname;
            friend.lastname = FriendModel.lastname;
            friend.postalcode = FriendModel.postalcode;
            friend.notes = FriendModel.notes;
            friend.address = FriendModel.address;
            friend.CountryId = FriendModel.Country.Id;
            friend.StateId = FriendModel.State.Id;
            db.SaveChanges();

            var friendModel = new FriendModel();
            friendModel.Id = friend.Id;
            friendModel.firstname = friend.firstname;
            friendModel.lastname = friend.lastname;
            friendModel.postalcode = friend.postalcode;
            friendModel.notes = friend.notes;
            friendModel.address = friend.address;
            friendModel.CountryId = friend.CountryId;
            friendModel.StateId = friend.StateId;
            return Json(friendModel);
        }
    }



public class BundleConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

            // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
            // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                      "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                      "~/Content/site.css"));


            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/angularjs").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/angular.min.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/appjs").Include(
                     "~/Scripts/app/customerCtrl.js"));
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you please add jsfiddle?

Comment: ok i will add but any partial solution  you want to give?

Comment: You using two selection list if user select first list (country) item  depending on that (states) second list  data will load  byng-change="GetStatesList()" . your were using another view to display this data with user EDIT option . if user change country again you call "GetStatesList() " .but here ng-change not working  this may be scope  issue between controllers or ng-model not properly used

Comment: yaa thats the problem.

Comment: Post your solution as answer . it will help others

Comment: yaa but i dont have any solution that is why i have asked here.

Comment: i posted my answer.it may help you ,otherwise add jsfiddle

Comment: First solution will help you shortly. don't forget add DI as $rootScope

Comment: country and state list does not change . so you can use as factory and add as DI in your controller to use .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73405/discussion-between-maria-pithia-and-j-srini-vasan).

Comment: try `$parent.GetStatesList()` inside `ng-repeat` `ng-change` event

Comment: @pankajparkar:yaa it is calling that method and by injecting $rootScope in controller and doing this:
function friendControllerTest($scope, $http,$rootScope) {
$rootScope.GetStatesList = function () {

Comment: @pankajparkar:with above code too(as suggested by srini vasan) this method is calling

Comment: adding method to the `$rootScope` doesn't sounds like good solution..

Comment: i think $parent scope does not work in this situation

Comment: @J.SRINIVasan  why it doesn't work? it would work

Comment: i suggest simple solution . other wise use factory / service methods  . this only good practice than  $parent ( $parent  will work only when using directives )

Comment: @J.SRINIVasan:yaa $parent worked

Comment: @pankajparkar:why using $rootscopet isnt a good solution?

Comment: sorry @pankajparkar . post as answer . you are correct. but i think nothing wrong with $rootScoop. may i know why using $rootscopet isnt a good solution?

Comment: @J.SRINIVasan read here http://michaeleconroy.blogspot.in/2013/09/dont-dirty-up-rootscope-create-global.html , I'm saying why to make available method to all childs for fixing it in one place

Comment: @pankajparkar:can you please explain me a little bit that how it worked with $parent??

Comment: @pankajparkar thats why i suggest  2. write service method/factory . but easy solution is rootscope.  i want why $parent , why not $rootScope .  but no answer in that blog

Comment: $parent only work , if  display controller  is child scope of friendControllerTest . but rootscope work overall app

Comment: @J.SRINIVasan you are not getting my point, there is no need to pollute `$rootScope` to get access it inside `ng-repeat`

Comment: @Maria Pithia please use $parent, because Mr.pankajparkar have experience .Net MVC  . it would be good solution than me .

Comment: @J.SRINIVasan hey experience doesn't matter, the solution does matter while fixing problem..Thanks :) I've updated the answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is you are accessing scope inside `ng-repeat` & Directive like `ng-repeat`, `ng-switch`, `ng-view`, `ng-include`& `ng-if` does create a new scope from currently running scope. For referring parent scope method or variable you need use `$parent`, that provides access to parent

You should first need to read [**Understanding of Angular Scope Inheritance**](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes).

[**Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/zZfUQN?p=preview) for Explanation of the same.

Below is the only change required inside you markup

```
ng-change="GetStatesList()"
```

to

```
ng-change="$parent.GetStatesList()"
```

Hope this could help you, Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**ng-change event not firing in Angularjs**

You have two views .

```
 1. Add record( give info to country ,state)
 2. Display stored records (with edit mode to change country,state)
```

In your add record view `ng-change="GetStatesList()"` fires and show state list by calling `GetStatesList()` function `friendControllerTest` when country selected (model value changed) .

Your **Display records view has its own controller.it doesn't have `GetStatesList()` function ,so that ng-change not working .

**Two solution for this issue is:**

```
 1. Make "$scope.GetStatesList()" to "$rootScope.GetStatesList()"- rootscope
 2. Write service/factory method then you can use wherever you want.
```

**EDIT:**
but using `$parent.GetStateList()` is good practice as @pankajparkar's soltution

Comment: but cant this be done without using method or factory??

Comment: modify you method to $rootScope and add $rootScope DI

Comment: that is two solution . first one easy to use

Comment: your service/factory suggestion +1 for